# check for item in list in Erlang

Tags: erlang, erl

I'm trying to make check function in Erlang
I have one word and list of word

```
list_word() ->
     ["bad1", "bad2", "bad3"].
```

And I'm trying to check if this word in list return true except return false

example :

```
check_list() ->
    badword = list_word(),
    if "bad1" == badword ->
        %% do some thing
```

in this case first word in list but second word not and I wan't it to return true

```
check_list() ->
    badword = list_word(),
    if "bad1 test" == badword ->
        %% do some thing
```

how can I do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [`lists:member/2`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#member-2) — it is implemented as a `BIF` so it's very fast.

```
case lists:member("bad1", list_word()) of
    true ->
        %% do something
        ;
    false ->
        ok
end.
```

**Edit**:
For your second example you can do something like:

```
Words = list_word(),
Found = fun(Word) -> lists:member(Word, Words) end,
BadWords = string:tokens("bad1 test", " "),
case lists:any(Found, BadWords) of
    true ->
        %% do something
        ;
    false ->
        ok
end.
```

Comment: @emzemzx: I recommend you to start with http://www.erlang.org/doc/getting_started/seq_prog.html

Comment: thanks, what if I add big word like this. lists:member("bad1 test", list_word())

first word in list but second word not, I wan't it to return true, can I ?

Comment: Then you have to be more specific. You can do something like `lists:any(fun(X) -> lists:member(X, list_word()) end, string:tokens("bad1 test", " "))` But there are many questions which comes up like why do you have `"bad1 test"` and not `["bad1", "test"]`, how expensive is `list_word()` call in real code and what is purpose of this code.